# Rare crash with Crypto++ pbkdf2::DeriveKey()

Tags: c++, crypto++, pbkdf2

I'm using the CryptoPP library to hash some passwords. About 1 in 10 times, it crashes on the DeriveKey line below, with a segfault.

Even when using fixed parameters the crashes still seem random. I'm wondering if perhaps I need a '\0' on the end of my strings. Or maybe the output buffer needs to be zero initialized, or something?

Anyway, here's the code.

```
#include <cryptopp/aes.h>
#include <cryptopp/algparam.h>
#include <cryptopp/filters.h>
#include <cryptopp/modes.h>
#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
#include <cryptopp/pwdbased.h>

int main()
{
CryptoPP::PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA256> pbkdf2;

CryptoPP::byte salt[16];

CryptoPP::byte key[32];

/* Hard coded for testing purposes */
Common::podFromHex("00f8807a289655b2a8e38cda00182a32", salt);

/* Hard coded for testing purposes */
std::string password = "a";

std::cout << "Salt: " << Common::podToHex(salt) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Salt size: " << sizeof(salt) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Password: " << password.data() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Password size: " << password.size() << std::endl;

/* Rare segfault on this line */
pbkdf2.DeriveKey(
    key, sizeof(key), 0, (CryptoPP::byte *)password.data(),
    password.size(), salt, sizeof(salt), Constants::PBKDF2_ITERATIONS
);
}
```

Everything seems initialized properly - the print statements give me the exact same thing every time:

```
Salt: 00f8807a289655b2a8e38cda00182a32
Salt size: 16
Password: a
Password size: 1
```

Furthermore - the hashed password is usable, when it doesn't segfault. I'm using AES encryption later on, and I can perfectly unencrypt the file, and all the data is as expected.

The source code for derive key can be found here, by the way: https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/pwdbased_8h_source.html#l00235

Thanks.

Comment: We need more information, like the relevant source code for the Common library. The exact line of the crash with a stack trace would be helpful, too. You should probably run your program under Valgrind or other memory checking tool, like Address Sanitizer.

Comment: I was thinking of running with valgrind - It's a bit of a pain since some of the surrounding code I'm using throws out a gigantic amount of errors - I should probably test this in a separate program. I'll get rid of the Common library for a better minimal example - I'm fairly sure there's no issue in that section of the code though, it's just converting to/from hex.

Comment: You should be Valgrind-clean at `-O1`. If you are observing lots of Valgrind findings at `-O1` then you probably have some issues you need to fix. Also see [The Valgrind Quick Start Guide | Preparing your program](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/QuickStart.html). ({Some|Many} findings at `-O2` and `-O3` are false positives).

Comment: Oh, absolutely, there are a ton of issues the current code base has - Trying to fix them slowly.

Comment: I am using Mingw and cant seem to get any of these crypto api(s) to work. They are poorly documented. But cheifly, they crash my program. Just calling cryptInit() from cryptlib causes a crash.

Answer (score 3):

I'm hazarding a guess, but `salt` is not NULL terminated. The program is probably accessing beyond the 16th element of the `salt` array:

```
std::cout << "Salt: " << Common::podToHex(salt) << std::endl;
```

---

The following executes multiple times without problems. It is your program less the calls to the Common library.

The call to `std::memcpy` only takes the left-most 16-bytes of the string. It does not do the conversion. (I only wanted to remove the call to Common).

```
$ cat test.cxx

#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "filters.h"
#include "sha.h"
#include "hex.h"
#include "files.h"
#include "pwdbased.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<SHA256> pbkdf2;

    byte salt[16], key[32];

    /* Hard coded for testing purposes */
    // Common::podFromHex("00f8807a289655b2a8e38cda00182a32", salt);
    std::memcpy(salt, "00f8807a289655b2a8e38cda00182a32", 16);

    /* Hard coded for testing purposes */
    std::string password = "a";

    // std::cout << "Salt: " << Common::podToHex(salt) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Salt: ";
    StringSource(salt, sizeof(salt), true, new HexEncoder(new FileSink(std::cout)));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Salt size: " << sizeof(salt) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Password: " << password.data() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Password size: " << password.size() << std::endl;

    /* Rare segfault on this line */
    pbkdf2.DeriveKey(
        key, sizeof(key), 0, (byte *)password.data(),
        password.size(), salt, sizeof(salt), 10000 /*Constants::PBKDF2_ITERATIONS*/
    );

    std::cout << "Key: ";
    StringSource(key, sizeof(key), true, new HexEncoder(new FileSink(std::cout)));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled and executed with:

```
$ g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 test.cxx -o test.exe ./libcryptopp.a
$ ./test.exe
Salt: 30306638383037613238393635356232
Salt size: 16
Password: a
Password size: 1
Key: F88BA6947B802C66F7E7A2BC0099AFD92C81DC293E3CC48C2DA3FA75E27ECE6B
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but isn't salt not null terminated in your example either? I'll test more tomorrow - I can probably get rid of the Common:: calls to make a better minimal example.

Comment: @Zpalmtree - Correct, but I am only encoding 16 bytes (which encodes to 32 chars) and then inserting the 32 bytes in `std::cout`. I am not relying on a NULL terminator.

Comment: Perhaps I've confused things by using the Common:: stuff to try and simplify the example - In actual usage I was using a method to generate 16 random bytes for salt. I can't seem to reproduce the error anymore, and valgrind gives nothing helpful. Tempted to blame it on cosmic rays, rare segfaults are very frustrating. :(

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this. It was not actually due to any of the code listed above, but it was because I was calling a function using this, in a signal handler.

Because this was taking quite a while to run (using 500,000 iterations) it appeared to be crashing here every time, but it was actually not due to this line.

I ended up fixing it flipping a bool flag in the signal handler, and having a separate thread watching that flag. When the flag was set, it called the destructor, which in turn triggered the normal shutdown flow, allowing all my threads to shutdown and save correctly.